# Case Console With Default Record Type

Tags: console

I have a case console enabled and have 2 different profiles.

For Profile 1 , there are different record types enabled and when I select a particular record type RT1  , side panel and highlight panel is  displayed correctly.

For Profile 2 , RT1 is default record type and I did not get record type selection screen and page loads correctly but side panel and highlight panel is not  displayed .